# Solve the following summation

Tags: combinatorics, summation

$S = \dfrac{n \choose 0}{1} + \dfrac{n \choose 1}{2} +  
 \dfrac{n \choose 2}{3}+\dotsb+\dfrac{n \choose n}{n+1}$

Comment: What have you tried?  Perhaps you can try expanding $\binom{n}{k}$ in terms of the component factorials, and reformulate each fraction so that the denominator doesn't depend on $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ We can write $$\displaystyle S = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\cdot \frac{1}{k+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{k!\cdot (n-k)!}\cdot \frac{1}{k+1}$$

$$\displaystyle S = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(n+1)!}{(k+1)!\cdot (n-k)!}=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{k+1} = \frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}.$$

Above we have used the Identity $$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k} = 2^n$$.

So for $$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{k+1} = 2^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 11):

We have $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}x^{k}=\left(1+x\right)^{n}
 $$ then $$\int_{0}^{1}\left(1+x\right)^{n}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}\int_{0}^{1}x^{k}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k+1}
 $$ and so $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k+1}=\int_{1}^{2}u^{n}du=\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}.
 $$